# iTerm2: Non standard characters are differently sized than other characters

Tags: iterm

Recently I changed iTerm2's default setting so that the default font size is larger when I open it up. However this increased font size only seems to apply to the standard characters. The non standard characters are still small when I open up iTerm2.

[image]

How can I make the non-standard characters the same size as the other characters?

Comment: What is the name of your font?

Comment: code new roman regular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untick `Use a different font for non-ASCII text`

[image]

To make this change first go to the preferences page. You can get to the preferences page either by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>or by going to the top left of the Iterm2 screen clicking "Iterm2" then "Preferences". Once at preferences, to get to the specific spot mentioned above it might be helpful to reference [this](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/uploads/b1db14be0c7cba4f21cf4ec7d059e62a/settings.png) picture.

Comment: That was the first thing that popped to my mind, too. If that's not it, I'd be flummoxed.